# Why umask 001 does not set execution permissions?

Tags: linux

I am new to Linux. I am making some trials with the umask command. I set the umask to 001 but when I create a file and the display a long list, the new file does not show allowed-execution permission. I wonder why?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Umask is a bit special. What setting a bit means is that you are actually disabling the permission. It implementation is:

```
(not umask) & filemode
```

The filemode is what the user would like to create.

So you disabled the execution bit:

```
001 -> complement -> 110 -> rw-
```

The mask you want to try is 110 (bits) or 006 (octal) :)

Comment: @glglgl That is true, that is due to whatever is creating the file. Umask works on desired file permissions. But he also doesn't understand the logic behind umask.

Comment: @glglgl 

Yes, it is  octal.

Answer (score 1):

The umask tells the system which bits to remove from the mode bitmask given at the [`creat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/creat.html) call. The umask is usually represented as an octal number, each digit consisting of 3 bits (`r`=4, `w`=2, `x`=1). The three octal digits stand for "user", "group", "other".

It is up to the program if it calls `creat` with the mode `666` for `rw-` or `777` for `rwx`. In this case, obviously `666` is used. (A file is normally created with `666` unless it is supposed to be executable. In this case, `777` is used. This counts e. g. for compilers.)

A very common `umask` is `022` (octal). It turns `666` (`rw-rw-rw-`) into `644` (`rw-r--r--`) and `777` (`rwxrwxrwx`) into `755` (`rwxr-xr-x`) These are, respectively, the file modes which are eventually applied to the file.

Your umask `001` would only switch off the `x` bit of the "others" group. So `777` would become `776` (`rwxrwxrw-`), and `666` stays `666` (`rw-rw-rw-`).

Comment: Thanks glglgl....but, what mask would allow me to get files with rwxrwxrw- permission?. I understood it would be 001 (octal)

Comment: @JCNunez Only if the program creating that file supports this by requesting mode `0777`. Otherwise, you'd do it by hand. `python -c 'import os, sys; os.close(os.open(sys.argv[1], os.O_CREAT, 0777))' 123123123` will create you the file `123123123` with all mode bits set. The umask then masks them out and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the system admin has set up a umask exception to not allow execute permissions to occur by default. See this article for more information:
http://boulderapps.co/on-create-a-new-file-why-are-the-execute-permissions-not-set-to-my-umask